# TS2322 Property missing in subclass, but it's there

Tags: angular, typescript

I have these two Angular 4 component classes.

The superclass:

```
export class SectionComponent implements OnInit {
  slides: SlideComponent[];

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

And the subclass:

```
export class FrontPageSectionComponent extends SectionComponent implements OnInit {
  slides: SlideComponent[];

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.slides = [];
  }

}
```

I try to create an array of superclasses in my AppComponent...

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  sections: SectionComponent[];

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sections = [
      FrontPageSectionComponent
    ];
  }
}
```

But I get an error:

> TS2322: Type 'typeof FrontPageSectionComponent[]' is not assignable to type 'SectionComponent[]'. Type 'typeof FrontPageSectionComponent' is not assignable to type 'SectionComponent'. Property 'slides' is missing in type 'typeof FrontPageSectionComponent'.

I haven't specified any types myself, and a search in the codebase for 'typeof FrontPageSectionComponent' yields nothing, so I assume this is TypeScript inference.

Answer (score 2):

your array

```
sections: SectionComponent[];
```

declares an array of `SectionComponent` instances.

If you want to declare an array of classes that derive from `SectionComponent`, you in fact can.

You need to use the type of the class *value*, not the type its instances.

To get the type of a value, use the `typeof` keyword.

```
const c: typeof SectionComponent = SectionComponent;
```

Hence, to declare an array of classes that construct instances of `SectionComponent` you would write.

```
sections: Array<typeof SectionComponent>;
```

More abstractly, you can write

```
sections: Array<new () => SectionComponent>;
```

Such techniques are very useful in higher order programming.

*Note I am using the `Array<...>` syntax purely for clarity when nesting, `[]` also works*

Comment: That's very interesting. Do you know any good sources for reading about this issue and that new () => SectionComponent syntax?

Also now, I made the Service I made take a FrontPageComponent in its constructor. With these changes it won't accept it into the array. How can I let a service provide an array of components?
Ultimately I would like to count sections with slides and provide a progress bar of how far the user has gotten through the presentation. I imagined providing those sections to a nav-bar through a service.
If this is complicated let me know and I'll start a new question.

Comment: Actually that syntax is not new. There's a fair amount of information on it if you look up the typescript typeof operator. I don't think you need to store an array of classes to accomplish what you're trying to do. The reason your service doesn't like this type declaration is because the incoming value is probably declared as an instance of the class and not the class itself or a subclass

Answer (score 0):

When I instead of `FrontPageComponent` inserted `new FrontPageComponent()` into the array, it worked.

So then I remembered something about Angular knowing how to construct these, and now I do this:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  sections: SectionComponent[];

  constructor(private frontPage: FrontPageSectionComponent) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sections = [
      this.frontPage,
    ];
  }
}
```

And the error is gone. If this is still the wrong practice please let me know.

I'm actually moving the sections to a SectionService to separate the concerns, (that constructor would fill up quickly,) but since I didn't find any good results when I googled this I'm putting this up.